# Poor tensorflow-lite accuracy in Android application

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I created a model based on "iris" example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

The only difference is 18 parameters instead of 4. Here is the trainig:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
print("Eager execution: {}".format(tf.executing_eagerly()))

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# meaningless column names (these are just points on path)
column_names = []
for i in range(18):
    column_names.append(str(i))
column_names.append('code')

feature_names = column_names[:-1]
label_name = column_names[-1]

print("Features: {}".format(feature_names))
print("Label: {}".format(label_name))

batch_size = 32

train_dataset_fp='gestures_dataset.csv'
test_fp='gestures_test_dataset.csv'

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    train_dataset_fp,
    batch_size,
    column_names=column_names,
    label_name=label_name,
    num_epochs=1)

features, labels = next(iter(train_dataset))

print(features)

def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
  """Pack the features into a single array."""
  features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1)
  return features, labels

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(pack_features_vector)

features, labels = next(iter(train_dataset))

print(features[:5])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(18,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(99) # max y
])

predictions = model(features)
predictions[:5]
tf.nn.softmax(predictions[:5])

print("Prediction: {}".format(tf.argmax(predictions, axis=1)))
print("    Labels: {}".format(labels))

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def loss(model, x, y, training):
  # training=training is needed only if there are layers with different
  # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
  y_ = model(x, training=training)

  return loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)


l = loss(model, features, labels, training=False)
print("Loss test: {}".format(l))

def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=True)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

loss_value, grads = grad(model, features, labels)

print("Step: {}, Initial Loss: {}".format(optimizer.iterations.numpy(),
                                          loss_value.numpy()))

optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

print("Step: {},         Loss: {}".format(optimizer.iterations.numpy(),
                                          loss(model, features, labels, training=True).numpy()))

## Note: Rerunning this cell uses the same model variables

# Keep results for plotting
train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []

num_epochs = 201

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
  epoch_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

  # Training loop - using batches of 32
  for x, y in train_dataset:
    # Optimize the model
    loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    # Track progress
    epoch_loss_avg.update_state(loss_value)  # Add current batch loss
    # Compare predicted label to actual label
    # training=True is needed only if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    epoch_accuracy.update_state(y, model(x, training=True))

  # End epoch
  train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
  train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())

  if epoch % 50 == 0:
    print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(epoch,
                                                                epoch_loss_avg.result(),
                                                                epoch_accuracy.result()))

print("Train Features: {}".format(feature_names))
print("Train Label: {}".format(label_name))

test_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    test_fp,
    batch_size,
    column_names=column_names,
    label_name='code',
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

test_dataset = test_dataset.map(pack_features_vector)


test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()

for (x, y) in test_dataset:
  # training=False is needed only if there are layers with different
  # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
  logits = model(x, training=False)
  prediction = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
  test_accuracy(prediction, y)

print("Test set accuracy: {:.3%}".format(test_accuracy.result()))

predict_dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor([
    [-1.71912153733768,-1.600284570848521,-1.5381268862069348,-1.4715348931204082,-1.288139905246001,-1.1430043332521034,-1.0377966435805905,-0.917447255766948,-0.8243115053236005,-0.7221500095444899,-0.6122901812467855,-0.5279331246212958,-0.4711441530129924,-0.42382317547383797,-0.379125249974646,-0.3584395324813018,-0.3773178934213158,-0.209925435991827], # 97
    [-1.719142448637883,-1.6070012986091102,-1.572271179903342,-1.5020486993447422,-1.228204782287214,-0.9707573015762415,-0.7300762773069808,-0.6385491168374685,-0.6184750884169654,-0.5158419098312659,-0.4242179680726442,-0.3985456036342834,-0.45447802906758966,-0.32393179755297036,-0.34842004414413613,-0.3137233709782729,-0.2703212385408242,-0.179563755582959], #97
    [-1.2434308209471674,-1.290953157205209,-1.227196227844711,-1.0484221580036261,-1.1187694579488316,-1.0359029865213372,-0.9530690852958581,-0.8660790849613064,-0.7502219135026331,-0.7117469449838862,-0.6296399221137823,-0.4460378665376745,-0.24453369606529932,-0.19766809148302653,-0.2370765208790035,-0.16973967297444315,-0.13099311119922252,-0.190617456158117], #97
    [0.0959563553661881,0.005325043913705397,-0.29823757321078925,-0.2705936526978625,-0.3951014272470887,-0.6356791899284542,-0.7295967272279017,-0.7692828405100477,-0.8921483861419475,-0.938276499224535,-1.1041582457726553,-0.9828524991149495,-1.2643027491255159,-1.2100579380905314,-1.3432258234528074,-1.3906264041632181,-1.4631851219015923,-1.550324747999713], #98
    [-0.4255400547149646,-0.4170633144859319,-0.30617172166256573,-0.32146197989889846,-0.3761100957494884,-0.47974793791908504,-0.49056452749853213,-0.591392915980335,-0.6902519118143285,-0.7964676298996293,-0.9360219373132298,-0.9111343228162241,-0.8983688928253518,-0.966734388774943,-0.9693728140937128,-1.1077741379921604,-1.2581032583883935,-1.49385364736419], #98
    [-0.08883842414482357,-0.17460057376690552,-0.20487321174320916,-0.34615149849742594,-0.4007630921307977,-0.5304849239297219,-0.6679686860060923,-0.7331022614090361,-0.8046170893211384,-0.8465804703035087,-0.9042750283451748,-1.052137679065288,-1.2453931454800324,-1.2529541366362975,-1.3787691439448853,-1.4353235462331002,-1.408970918123915,-1.542773717680230] #98
])

# training=False is needed only if there are layers with different
# behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
predictions = model(predict_dataset, training=False)

for i, logits in enumerate(predictions):
  class_idx = tf.argmax(logits).numpy()
  p = tf.nn.softmax(logits)[class_idx]
  print("Example {} prediction: {} ({:4.1f}%)".format(i, class_idx, 100*p))

print("Saving...")

model.save('gestures.h5')
```

Then .h5 is converted to .tflite and tested on my test dataset:

gest_tflite.py:

```
#!python

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# generate .tflite file from .h5 file
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('gestures.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("gestures.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)    

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="gestures.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
print("input_shape: ", input_shape)


from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('android.csv', delimiter=',')
X = my_data[:,0:18]
y = my_data[:,18]

i = 0
for g in X:
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], np.array([g], dtype=np.float32))

    interpreter.invoke()

    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    logits = output_data[0]
    class_idx = tf.argmax(logits).numpy()
    p = tf.nn.softmax(logits)[class_idx]
    print("recognized code {} ({:4.1f}%), original code {}".format(class_idx, 100*p, y[i]))
    i += 1
```

It works great:

```
recognized code 97 (80.8%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (91.0%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (86.1%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (84.2%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (90.5%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (80.0%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (91.8%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (85.7%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (80.5%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (89.8%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (87.4%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (78.6%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (77.8%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (86.7%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (85.6%), original code 97.0
recognized code 97 (85.3%), original code 97.0
recognized code 98 (96.8%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (97.3%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (95.2%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (93.3%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (91.7%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (93.8%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (93.1%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (93.3%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (94.1%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (98.6%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (96.0%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (86.6%), original code 98.0
recognized code 98 (94.1%), original code 98.0
```

So, .tflite is ok. But now I use the same .tflite file on the same test data in Android, using Android Studio 4.1 to add .tflite model to my code:

```
    public static int my_argmax(float[] array) {
        if (array.length <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array is empty");
        float max = array[0];
        int maxi=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
            if (array[i] > max) {
                max = array[i];
                maxi = i;
            }
        return maxi;
    }

    private int do_classify(float f[]) {
        int retcode = -1;
        Log.d("DE", "do_classify: Begin");
        Log.d("DE", "do_classify: input array size = " + f.length);
        Context c = getApplicationContext();
        try {
            Gestures model = Gestures.newInstance(c);

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, f.length}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(f.length*4);

            for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                bb.putFloat(f[i]);
            }
            bb.rewind();

            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(bb);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            Gestures.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            float res[] = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
            int size = outputFeature0.getFlatSize();
            retcode = my_argmax(res); // find out index of max element
            Log.d("DE","do_classify: outputFeature0 size = " + size);
            Log.d("DE","do_classify: datatype = " + outputFeature0.getDataType());
            Log.d("DE","do_classify: max = " + retcode);
            model.close();
            Log.d("DE", "do_classify: model.close()");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DE", "do_classify: IO Exception");
        }
        Log.d("DE", "do_classify: retcode = " + retcode);
        return retcode;
    }
    private void onClassify() {
        List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/sdcard/Documents/gst/gestures.csv"));) {
            String[] values = null;
            while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                records.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }

            float[] argg = new float[18];
            for(int i=0; i< records.size(); i++) {
                List<String> strn = records.get(i);
                Log.d("DE", "onClassify: begin CSV line #" + i + " size = " + strn.size());
                for (int y=0; y < strn.size(); y++) {
                    if (y<18) {
                        Log.d("DE", "onClassify y = " + y + " value = " + strn.get(y));
                        try {
                            argg[y] = Float.parseFloat(strn.get(y));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            Log.d("DE","onClassify: ERROR: " + ex.toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        int ret = do_classify(argg);
                        Thread.sleep(100); // sometimes classification fails without this delay
                        Log.d("DE", "onClassify: recognized code " + ret + ", original code " + strn.get(y));
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d("DE","onClassify: records = " + records.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("DE","onClassify: ERROR: " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DE","onClassify: ERROR: " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        } catch (CsvValidationException e) {
            Log.d("DE","onClassify: ERROR: " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("DE", "onClassify: ERROR: " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        Log.d("DE","onClassify: end");
    }
```

And I get about 1/3 classifications wrong:

```
recognized code 98, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 98, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 0, original code 97
recognized code 98, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 98, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 97, original code 97
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 97, original code 98
recognized code 97, original code 98
recognized code 97, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 97, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 97, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
recognized code 98, original code 98
```

Can't say that Android results are complete garbage, but accuracy is way too low to be usable. What's wrong with Android part if the same .tflite model works *great* in python and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. It seems like the problem was with the way the model was converted. Adding below lines fixed the tflite model for me.

```
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
        tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
        tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS  # enable TensorFlow ops.
    ]
converter.experimental_enable_resource_variables = True
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Rebuilt tflite model, rebuilt android binary, the same problem. What version of tensorflow and tflite you are using?...